# Linux From Scratch 7.10 issue, EFI partition

Tags: external-hdd, uefi, lfs

Just a little background information, I am taking a Unix II course, instructor being Bruce Dubbs, the managing editor for the LFS.org project.

I am building LFS in a Debian 8.6 host for a Unix II course.

Everything went great up until the configuring grub to boot LFS section, then things went a little strange.

Instructor states we are to skip the grub portion of LFS 7.10, comes to each of our systems, and goes thru the established grub.cfg file, erasing most of it, and manually configuring what is left.  Note, he does not explain what he is doing.

Everyone else is up and running save for my installation, which has been set up and run on an external SSD, running on an MSI GL62 laptop, while everyone else is using quite older hardware.

Long story short, instructor states that he has not tested LFS on EFI partitions, while there is documentation on the LFS site itself stating that it works on EFI partitions.

With my course final this coming Thursday, and a running LFS build being a major part of the grade, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Libertarian Futurist Society?

Comment: Edited question line to be more obvious.  Also, the tag lfs exists therefore I ass+u+me(d) that LFS would be a known quantity.   But with my professors political leanings........your original guess would be accurate as well.

Comment: might need to fix that processor before it goes nuts! :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Everyone else is up and running save for my installation, which has been set up and run on an external SSD, running on an MSI GL62 laptop, while everyone else is using quite older hardware.

Oh blast. It's hard to watch when people with ancient hardware get ahead of you in a project that mainly involves compiling stuff.

> With my course final this coming Thursday, and a running LFS build being a major part of the grade, any help would be appreciated.

I suggest ditching EFI boot. Your firmware should be able to boot legacy MBR. So make sure your DOS partition table is accurate with fdisk and install grub stage1.5 to the MBR and slack space following it.

Comment: Shall give this a try, though keeping the Win10 installation happy is a must, as other courses require it...../sarcastic yay.   I did try going about LFS in a virtual environment which led to.....nothing.  Will mark as accepted, as this answer makes the most sense,

Comment: well you can rush through http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html and on but that's risky in this particular situation, external SSD bootable in Legacy/CSM/BIOS mode is enough to leave win10s bootable in UEFI mode (you might need to repartition it to DOS/MBR from GPT though if CSM won't boot off GPT)